# Implementing Custom Interfaces similar to Comparable Interface

Tags: apex, list, wrapper-class, interface

I've a list of wrapper objectsin my controller for which I need to perform some operation(say doLogic()). I want to use the method similar to calling sort method.

```
listOfWrappers.doLogic();

//similar to sort
listOfWrappers.sort();
```

As per my understanding, I need to create a public interface like `myInterface` and my `myWrapper` class will have to implement the interface.

What is the next step? How exactly do I get it to work?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort method `list<Object>.sort()` is a method that already exists on `list<Object>`. The Comparable interface can be implemented on an **apex object** so that `list<Object>.sort()` can sort those apex objects.

You seem to be asking how to add a brand new method `doLogic()` to `list<Object>` so that you can call `list<Object>.doLogic()`. I don't think this is going to be possible. What you can do is write `MyUtilityClass.doLogic(list<MyWrapperClass>)` to process your list of wrappers.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a confirmation. I'll keep the question open for sometime to get other ideas(if any).